# Replace the use of $where in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb, nosql

I have a question, I need to compare if the division of two fields is greater or equal than some value. So the solution I've found is:

```
{
    "$where": "this.total / this.limit > 0.6"
}
```

But the docs says that the use of $where isn't good for performance, because it will run a javascript function, and lose the indexes.

Does someone has a better solution for this, that doesn't use $where?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move to the aggregation framework here using divide ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_divide ):

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: whatever_or_whatever_clause_you_want}},
    {$project: {
        // Your document fields
        divided_limit: {$divide: ['$total', '$limit']}
    }},
    {$match: {divided_limit: {$gt: 0.6}}}
]);
```

Note: the aggregation framework is new since v2.1

> But the docs says that the use of $where isn't good for performance, because it will run a javascript function, and lose the indexes

You can't use an index for this anyway, there is no way to use an index for mathematical functions like this. The key thing is that the JS engine is up to 16X slower than normal querying, the aggregation framework should be faster. Not only that but the JS lock is global for all queries.

Of course the fastest method is to pre-aggregate this sum into another field upon modifying the record in your application, then you won't need any of this, just a normal query.